# Simple Python Caesar Cipher

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, module

This is my simple Caesar Cipher program that is not functioning correctly:

```
BASE = ord("a")
letter = input("Enter the message you want to encrypt:")
shift = int(input("The number you want to shift by: "))
lower_case = letter.lower
shift = BASE
new_strs = [""]
for character in lower_case:
    new_strs.append(chr(BASE + ord(character) - shift) %26)
print ("".join(new_strs))
```

I want to create modulus 26. In other words if the number to shift by is 27, then the program loops back to the start of the alphabet a-z. I have also been having problems when you leave a space in the message. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check that a new character is in a-z, A-Z before attempting to shift it.  Pass non-alphabetic characters, like spaces, through to `new_strs` unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    '''I added some parantheses and deleted the command shift = BASE '''

    BASE = ord("a")
    letter = input("Enter the message you want to encrypt:")
    shift = int(input("The number you want to shift by: "))
    # added ()
    lower_case = letter.lower()
    new_strs = [""]
    for character in lower_case:
        c   = (ord(character) - BASE + shift) % 26  
    new_strs.append(chr(c + BASE))
    print ("".join(new_strs))
```